# Incorrect date/time parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, time

I have my own application `myapp` that prints date from log file, such as:

```
myapp | xargs echo

Thu Sep 5 12:57:50 2013
```

But when I pass its output to `date`, I experience an error:

```
myapp | xargs date -d

date: extra operand `5'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

I need to calculate a date/time difference between current date/time and such date/time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just one parameter you can use:

```
date -d "$(myapp)"
```

Answer (score 3):

`date -d` expects one string, but gets multiple arguments. For the timestamp to be treated as a single string, you need to add quotes.

```
myapp | xargs -I% date -d "%"
```

Comment: @Ωmega use ``%s`` format to get seconds of both dates and then simply subtract.